# Set element value where element attribute has specific value

Tags: javascript

I have the following element

`<input type="text" size="4" name="nightly" value="-1">`

I would like to set the `value` to `15.9`. This should only be performed where `name="nightly"`

I have tried the following

`document.getElementsByName('name')['nightly'].setAttribute('value', '15.9');`

which returns error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByName('name')['nightly'].setAttribute')`

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName()` returns an array of all elements matching that name.

If only one element is ever returned you could do this:

```
document.getElementsByName('nightly')[0].setAttribute('value', '15.9'); //the 0 indicates the first and only element in the array.
```

If you expect multiple elements you could loop through the array:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('nightly');

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].setAttribute('value', '15.9');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName('nightly').forEach(function(val) {val.value = 15.9});
```

i hope it is what you are looking for.